# How can I redirect to the local url in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I had integrated payUmoney in my application and in the succes url when I am giving my local url which is http://localhost:3000/#!/payment then it is not working that time and when I refreshes the url it works good.what is the problem behind that?

Comment: can you show your route file

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try :
    app.controller('testController', ["$scope",  "$state", function ($scope,  $state) {

```
  $scope.payment = function () {      
    //payment  check here

    $state.go('payment'); //redirect to payment page with payment name of state in route       
  }
}]);
```

Route

```
 $stateProvider
      .state('payment', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "/app/views/home/payment.html",
          controller: "homeController"
      })
```

Comment: but in the payUmoney success url we have to provide the whole url where we want to redirect it there how can I provide only payment.I have to provide whole link which is  http://localhost:3000/#!/payment

Answer (score 0):

Use routing in angularJS

```
    var app = angular.module("appName", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'view1.html',
            controller: 'FirstController'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'view2.html',
            controller: 'SecondController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/view1'
        });
});
```

Check running demo here [AngularJS routing](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)